# Understanding the purpose of the underscore in grails templates

Tags: grails, gsp

Working with grails templates and the render method isn't that hard. 
I worked with it for a while now.

It's okay for me to deal with the 'Convention over Configuration'. And so it is with the needed underscore "_" at the beginning of the filename of a template .gsp file.

I'm not that experienced with programming in general, I'm doing an apprenticeship as a 'IT-specialist for application development' since 2,5 years now. So my background knowledge isn't that big yet.

But I'd now really like to understand what exactly the purpose of that underscore is. 
How's grails dealing with files with a leading underscore in comparison to those without it?

Comment: I don't think my opinion is answer worthy as I don't have links/docs to back me up, but underscore in front of files is just widely accepted standard of how template files are read. It is made, so if view file needs a template, you don't need to create a new name for it. Just name it _view.gsp. Plus template files are easier to differ in directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String view='/path/to/file'
def model= [template:view,instance:bean]
render(view:view, model:model)
```

this tells that template is `'/path/to/_file.gsp'` when it renders the template bit

when it renders view it looks for `'/path/to/file.gsp'`

so when you do render **view** it looks for files **without underscore**
when you do render **template** it looks for those **with underscore**

above example does both to explain how it works

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out the underscore indicates that the file is a template. However, the question still remains "what's the purpose?"

The purpose of a template is to provide a way to render a reusable fragment of view code. This allows you to compose very complex views (e.g. think functional decomposition). Templates aren't decorated by the sitemesh layout. This is very important when doing partial page updates with AJAX (or similar technology).

The [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/ref/Tags/render.html) actually explains templates quite well.